# Is it always possible to "encircle" exactly $n$ points in an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ without limit points?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis

Let $d$ be a positive integer, and let $\mathbb{R}^d$ be endowed with the
Euclidean metric. Given an infinite set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ without limit points
and a positive integer $n$, is there always a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a radius
$r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that the $r$-neighbourhood of $p$ contains *exactly* $n$
points in $S$?

If the answer is *yes*, what can be said in general about in which metric spaces this holds?

Comment: It is impossible for metric trees. The same argument as Andre's shows that it is possible in the case of connected Riemannian manifolds.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is possible.

Pick $p$ generic, so that
$$\not \exists\,\,\, x,y\in S\quad\text{s.t.}\quad d(p,x)=d(p,y).$$

Then slowly increase the radius until the $r$-neighborhood of $p$ contains exactly $n$ points of $S$.

Comment: Does the argument hold in $Q^d$? That is, how one would show that it's always possible to pick $p\in Q^d$ non-equidistant from $x,y\in S$?

Comment: Thanks. -- That answers the first question (and also shows that one probably
shouldn't ask questions which are too far off one's area of expertise!).

Comment: @Michael: No, $\mathbb{Q}^d$ is countable. Take an enumeration of the points, and eliminate each one by adding a pair of points to $S$ at the same distance from that point. These pairs can be chose so that there is no limit point of $S$, say by making the distance from the origin be at least $i$ for each point of the $i$th pair added. Some other argument may work to enclose $n$ points, but you can't just choose a generic center and expand a sphere about this center.

Comment: Take a disc that encloses much more than n points. Find a point in $\mathbb Q^d$ very close to the center of the disc which is generic with respect to all the points of the disc.  Then choose a radius such that only n points in the disc are in that radius. If the new center is sufficiently close to original center, all points in the new disc will be in the old disc, because the new radius is smaller.